# Adding item to Context menu, Visual Studio Addin

Tags: c#, add-in

I am trying to add an item to the context menu in Visual Studio using the Addin project. See image below for exact location

[image: Where I Want VS Addin Item to Go]

The following code is what i have so far, but is not working as expected:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
        if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
        {
            object []contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
            Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
            string toolsMenuName = "Add";

            //Place the command on the tools menu.
            //Find the MenuBar command bar, which is the top-level command bar holding all the main menu items:
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar ctxCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Context Menus"];
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar ctxProjectCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)ctxCommandBar)["Project"];

            //Find the Tools command bar on the MenuBar command bar:
            CommandBarControl toolsControl = ctxProjectCommandBar.Controls[toolsMenuName];
            CommandBarPopup toolsPopup = (CommandBarPopup)toolsControl;

            //This try/catch block can be duplicated if you wish to add multiple commands to be handled by your Add-in,
            //  just make sure you also update the QueryStatus/Exec method to include the new command names.
            try
            {
                //Add a command to the Commands collection:
                Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "MyAddin1", "MyAddin1", "Executes the command for MyAddin1", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

                //Add a control for the command to the tools menu:
                if((command != null) && (toolsPopup != null))
                {
                    command.AddControl(toolsPopup.CommandBar, 1);
                }
            }
            catch(System.ArgumentException)
            {
                //If we are here, then the exception is probably because a command with that name
                //  already exists. If so there is no need to recreate the command and we can 
                //  safely ignore the exception.
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what i may be doing wrong?

TIA